# How to convert your Spring Mvc maven based Java Project into an app

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, web-applications

I have an Advance Java based project  prepared on Spring Mvc framework with Hibernate. My requirement is to wrap it up into an app n publish it.
So, How should I proceed with it because I have faced many issues even at creating a war of the same.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to have a robust app, then you would have to create that from scratch. If the app is going to be for android, you can do that using **Java, Kotlin**... if it is going to be an IOS app then you would have to probably use **SWIFT** for this purpose. You can always use **Google Flutter** to create a beautiful responsive and robust app that would smoothly work on **Android and IOS devises.**

**Please note**: you would need to connect your app to the same server/database that your spring project connects to so they are both consistent as far as data is concerned....

Comment: as a start I am not focusing on creating a robust app rather at first I am just looking for a android app working like it should as a website.

Comment: Then you have two options, you use website-to-app converters which literally all they do is make your website open like it would in a browser, which does not look professional and is never smooth. The second is to create some basic layout using a certain framework or language and then get the data through an API... Hope this helps clear up some of your ambiguities...

Comment: yeah i was thinking of the second one through Restful API

Comment: Yes, that is your best option for so many reasons. First and foremost you would learn a lot along the way. Second, your app would look so professional. If you this my answer does clarify your ambiguities, please mark is as a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your app serves HTML of some sort. I also assume that by "app" you mean an app on mobile phones.

You have two options:

**Difficult one:** build a client-server architecture by exposing an API (easiest one is REST based) then build a separate Android and iPhone client that connects to your backend.

**Easy one:** use a tool like https://gonative.io/ (not affiliated, just first result by googling "android webpage into app"). Those kinds of tools create an app which just loads a browser and opens your page in it.

Usually, the "easy" option is frowned upon, but it is MUCH better in terms of time to market.

Comment: Tools like https://gonative.io/ do not really create apps. They just give you the ability to access your website through a an app-like web browser, which if that is the case, why not just have your clients open up your website using a web browser to begin with ?

Comment: yeah i have seen many a times instance of website opening as an app view in mobile. For a website i need to convert it to war n then publish it that wont be a problem i think but thinking of an app view would be a great deal

Comment: @bezmax yes the app is jsp based so it has lots of html embedded